# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException:

Tags: android, gradle

I am  developing a cv app and getting following exceptions
 on gradle file I have tried all possible solution invalidate cache restart and clean gradle did not work
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:

```
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException:
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\56.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\57.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\58.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\59.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\60.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\61.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\62.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\63.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\64.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\65.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\66.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\67.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\68.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\69.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\70.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\71.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\72.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\73.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\74.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\75.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\76.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\77.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\78.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\79.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\80.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\81.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\82.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\83.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\84.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\85.jar, C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NewsApp-master\KitabSawtiClone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\86.jar
```

> below app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "activity.drawer.navigation.com.kitabsawticlone"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.ncornette.cache:okcache-control:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc1'


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** I generally follow
Go to your project folder location

Step 1: delete build folder

Step 2: go folder projectfolder > app > build delete it

**Option 2:**

Step 1: Clean project
[image]

Step 2: Rebuild project
[image]

Comment: Make sure all your support libraries are same as compileSdkVersion of your build.gradle(Module:app)

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: I have added I think all necessary support libraries what other problem do you think

Comment: I have added multixdex dependcy as well

Comment: yeah I have seen

Comment: maybe there are something in dependcy  I did not understand where exactly

Comment: any hints and other approaches

Comment: I think the package you are importing (implementation) may have different version dependencies in internal modules.

Comment: Please have a look on this ans, may get some hint https://stackoverflow.com/a/51497500/2003526 how to remove dependencies

Comment: was it helpful?

Comment: it is the same still the same

Comment: Maybe I will post full logcat here or gist link

Comment: what is your suggestion